Modificar consulta de mysqli a sql server
Tengo esta consulta que funcion perfecto en mysqli:
SELECT *, COUNT(*) total2 FROM salidas JOIN usr ON salidas.s_usr = usr.tkn WHERE salidas.s_aas = '$m_ano' GROUP BY salidas.s_usr HAVING COUNT(*) >=1

Esa consulta imprime resultados en un ciclo while asi:
while($rowc2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlcon2)){

  echo '
  <tr>
  <td>'.$rowc2['nom'].'</td>
  <td>'.$rowc2['total2'].'</td>
  </tr>
  
  ';
}

Ahora necesito esa misma consulta pero que funcione en sql server donde me da error porque no me deja agrupar por algun motivo, no entiendo mucho de sql server, trate de ajustarla asi:
    SELECT salidas.*, usr.*, SalidaCounts.total2
FROM salidas
JOIN (
    SELECT s_usr, COUNT(*) AS total2
    FROM salidas
    WHERE s_aas = @m_ano
    GROUP BY s_usr
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1
) AS SalidaCounts ON salidas.s_usr = SalidaCounts.s_usr
JOIN usr ON salidas.s_usr = usr.tkn
WHERE salidas.s_aas = @m_ano;

pero no funciona porque no me agrupa por el criterio de salidas.s_usr.
Si alguien sabe como puedo hacer, le agradezco de antemano.

Es difícil recrear tu escenario, a no ser que proporciones un backup de tu DB para armarlo en ambos lados. Que errores te da? (si es que te da algún error)

No te deja hacerlo en sql server, porque ya en mysql (no mysqli, eso es un componente de php, no un motor de db) ya estaba mal.. mira aca, ajusta tu consulta a lo que necesitas y vas a poder arreglarlo sin mas...

La sintaxis de MySQL estuvo rota por mucho tiempo. Lo que no tiene sentido es esa consulta, pero si explicas la salida que buscas obtener, junto a la estructura relevante de la tabla, seguro encuentras ayuda. Si [edit] la pregunta, déjame una mención y veo si está en mis manos darte la consulta correcta.

Me queda la duda de la razón de ser del HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1. Eso regresará todos los valores.

Me parece que lo que buscas se puede obtener por medio de la instrucción OVER() para convertir las funciones de agregado en funciones de ventana.
SELECT SalidaCounts.*
FROM (
    SELECT *, 
           COUNT(*) OVER( PARTITION BY s_usr) AS total2
    FROM salidas
    WHERE s_aas = @m_ano
) AS SalidaCounts 
WHERE SalidaCounts.total2 >= 1;

